# Is it possible to include the pseudo element inside it's parent element css

Tags: css, pseudo-element

I would like to format my css such that each relevant element is within their own class, including the class's pseudo-elements.
Currently, the pseudo-element is formatted this way.

```css
element {
   ...
}

element::after {
   ...
}
```

Is it possible to format the above into this format? Basically nesting the pseudo-element inside it's parent element.

```
element {
   ...
   element::after {
      ...
   }
}
```

Comment: Pure CSS doesn't allow you to nesting, preprocessor like [SASS](https://sass-lang.com/) will allow you to do this and this just one of the feature.

Also your pseudo element declaration is wrong it should be `element::after { }` (double colon).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not with vanilla css.
You have a few options, such as [Scss](https://sass-lang.com/guide#topic-3), [Less](https://lesscss.org/#nesting), [Stylus](https://stylus-lang.com/docs/selectors.html#parent-reference) and [Postcss](https://postcss.org/)([with a plugin](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-nested)).

If you're just starting, I'd recommend Scss:

```
.element {
  &::after {
  }
}
```